# Hide related videos in youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-api

I'm trying to hide related videos(youtube iframe) but it seems like it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id = "frame_container">
<iframe id="frame" width="800" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
<button onclick="hide_related()">Hide</button>
</div>

<script>
    function hide_related(){
        $("#frame_container").contents().find(".ytp-pause-overlay ytp-scroll-min").css("display", "none");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing the hashtag on the ID, also, where are the related videos in the DOM? The problem probably comes from `.contents()` only looking into the **immediate children** of the element, in this case the immediate children of `frame_container`.

Comment: This question probably needs the `jquery` tag.

Comment: Check my another answer which helps you a lot.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62776668/12078109)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the hashtag on the `jQuery` selector, it should be `$("#frame_container).

Also, the function `.contents()` only looks at the **immediate** children of the jQuery object/s obtained.

From the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/contents/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .contents() method allows us to search through the immediate children of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

```
<div id = "frame-container">
  <iframe id="frame" width="800" height="600" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
  </iframe>
  <button onclick="hide_related()">Hide</button>
</div>

<script>
  function hide_related() {
    $("#frame-container").find(".ytp-pause-overlay ytp-scroll-min")
      .css("display", "none");
  }
</script>
```